# About Advantages of js & css merge , minify in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, knockoutjs

Advantages of js & css merge , minify in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing good.

It's one of the ways to optimize Magento store speed or decrease the number of page load time.

**If you want to merge CSS files in Magento 2:**

Open the Admin panel, click Stores. In the Settings section, select Configuration.
Select Developer > Advanced in the panel on the left, open the CSS Settings section, and just hit YES or NO (option) as per your need.

In the Merge CSS Files field, select Yes! When you're done, click Save Config.

**To merge JavaScript files in Magento 2:**

On the Admin panel, click Stores. In the Settings section, select Configuration.
Select Developer under Advanced in the panel on the left, open the JavaScript Settings section, and In the Merge JavaScript Files field, select Yes! Once done, click Save Config.

For more further detail on JS bundling, do check out this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html